# How to generate Javadoc from command line

Tags: java, command-line, javadoc

Can anybody show me how to generate Javadoc from command line?

My project contains the package `com.test` and I want to put the generated documentation in files located in a specific folder like this: `C:/javadoc/test`.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the following: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#runningjavadoc

Answer (score 50):

You can refer the [javadoc 8 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html)

I think what you are looking at is something like this:

```
javadoc -d C:\javadoc\test com.test
```

Comment: It automatically appends extra '/' after package name for me, like if package is : `com.test` and inside there is Main class then, it should make output as `com/test/Main.html` but it will try to write to file `com/test//Main.html` , weird!

Comment: Yay, this worked on Linux too. `javadoc -d path/to/output/folder myClass.java`

Answer (score 29):

Oracle provides some simple examples:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDJBGFC

Assuming you are in ~/ and the java source tree is in ./saxon_source/net and you want to recurse through the whole source tree net is both a directory and the top package name.

```
mkdir saxon_docs
javadoc -d saxon_docs -sourcepath saxon_source -subpackages net
```

Comment: -subpackages was the key piece of info I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Let's say you have the following directory structure where you want to generate javadocs on `file1.java` and `file2.java` (package com.test), with the javadocs being placed in `C:\javadoc\test`:

```
C:\
|
+--javadoc\
|  |
|  +--test\
|
+--projects\
   |
   +--com\
      |
      +--test\
         |
         +--file1.java
         +--file2.java
```

In the command terminal, navigate to the root of your package: `C:\projects`. If you just want to generate the standard javadocs on all the java files inside the project, run the following command (for multiple packages, separate the package names by spaces):

```
C:\projects> javadoc -d [path to javadoc destination directory] [package name]

C:\projects> javadoc -d C:\javadoc\test com.test
```

If you want to run javadocs from elsewhere, you'll need to specify the sourcepath. For example, if you were to run javadocs in in `C:\`, you would modify the command as such:

```
C:\> javadoc -d [path to javadoc destination directory] -sourcepath [path to package directory] [package name]

C:\> javadoc -d C:\javadoc\test -sourcepath C:\projects com.test
```

If you want to run javadocs on only selected .java files, then add the source filenames separated by spaces (you can use an asterisk (*) for a wildcard). Make sure to include the path to the files:

```
C:\> javadoc -d [path to javadoc destination directory] [source filenames]

C:\> javadoc -d C:\javadoc\test C:\projects\com\test\file1.java
```

More information/scenarios can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html).

Comment: Just do something like C:\> javadoc -d C:\javadoc\test C:\projects\com\test\\*.java           JavaDoc is so frustrating to use otherwise (In Windows at least).

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 9):

For example if I had an application source code structure that looked like this:

- C:\b2b\com\steve\util\
- C:\b2b\com\steve\app\
- C:\b2b\com\steve\gui\

Then I would do:

```
javadoc -d "C:\docs" -sourcepath "C:\b2b" -subpackages com
```

And that should create javadocs for source code of the com package, and all subpackages (recursively), found inside the "C:\b2b" directory.

Answer (score 7):

its simple go to the folder where your all java code is saved say E:/javaFolder and then `javadoc *.java`

example

`E:\javaFolder> javadoc *.java`

Answer (score 4):

The answers given were not totally complete if **multiple** **sourcepath** and subpackages have to be processed.

The following command line will process all the packages under com **and** LOR (lord of the rings) located into /home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo/src/main/java **and** /home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo/src/test/java/

Please note:

- it is Linux and the paths and packages are separated by ':'
- that I made usage of private and wanted all the classes and members to be documented

---

```
rudy@rudy-ThinkPad-T590:~$ javadoc -d /home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo_doc
-sourcepath /home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo/src/main/java/
:/home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo/src/test/java/
-subpackages com:LOR 
-private

rudy@rudy-ThinkPad-T590:~/IdeaProjects/demo/src/main/java$ ls -R 
.: com LOR
./com: example
./com/example: demo
./com/example/demo: DemowApplication.java
./LOR: Race.java TolkienCharacter.java

rudy@rudy-ThinkPad-T590:~/IdeaProjects/demo/src/test/java$ ls -R 
.: com
./com: example
./com/example: demo
./com/example/demo: AssertJTest.java DemowApplicationTests.java
```

Answer (score 2):

```
D:\>javadoc *.java
```

If you want to create dock file of lang package then path should be same where your lang package is currently.  For example, I created a folder name `javaapi` and unzipped the `src` zip file, then used the command below.

```
C:\Users\Techsupport1\Desktop\javaapi\java\lang> javadoc *.java
```

Answer (score 1):

[Link to JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html)

I believe this will surely help you.

```
javadoc -d C:/javadoc/test com.mypackage
```