# How to read the javadoc comments which are there in the java class?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have few java classes which contain the javadoc comments . I want to extract the comments for some purpose. Is there any way to extract those comments ?

Comment: The answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592396/how-to-generate-javadoc-from-command-line

Comment: I Believe this can help you my friend

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504013/how-to-read-javadoc-comments-by-reflection][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504013/how-to-read-javadoc-comments-by-reflection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the doclet API. Here is a simple  [tutorial from oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html). The api will allow you to scan the metadata tags and also get the commentText.