# JavaDoc error: datatypeConverter doesnot exist

Tags: java, javadoc

Hi i am doing some school project on java and I am required to do Java Doc but whenever I tried to generate through eclipse.

error: package javax.xml.bind does not exist
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
                     ^
 error: package javax.xml.bind does not exist
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

These error appear. Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you might be running `javadoc` on Java 9 or later, where JAXB was removed.

Comment: @Andreas i just updated my javadoc ,will downgrade to 8 work?

Answer (score 0):

What JDK version are you using?

If you are using 11+ then it could be because `java.xml.bind` package was removed in Java 11.

Try to add the following dependency to your `POM.xml` (or `build.gradle`):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Either try to downgrade your java version

Comment: Stepess , Where is that ?? i could not find it.

Comment: @UniqueBhattarai, Do you use a build tool in your project? Like `maven` or `gradle`?

Comment: and could you please attach the output of `java --version` command?

Comment: no i am using the java doc for my academic project and I am using java swing

Comment: @UniqueBhattarai, and what about JDK version? Afaik, all version from 10 and down should work, but better to use 8 if it is not critical

Comment: ava version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: @UniqueBhattarai, I'm not a big expert in Eclipse, but I suppose that something could wrong on that side. You can try to generate `javadoc` using the [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592396/how-to-generate-javadoc-from-command-line)